# Built in display Color Profiles are not being applied in Mac OSX Mojave

Tags: display, mojave, screen, color

I'm using Mojave on an 11" 2015 MacBook Air. I was using the orangish **Color LCD** display profile until it was automatically changed to **sRGB**. Now the screen is bluish. Selecting **Color LCD** profile does nothing at all.

Restarting, calibrating, and repairing doesn't help. I also don't see my built-in display under ColorSync devices. Night shift doesn't work either.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you're saying that Color LCD used to display as you wanted it, but it now doesn't? And that creating a new profile doesn't change the color either? You say "I don't see my built-in display", do you mean in ColorSync Utility? Have you run First Aid?
Uncheck "show profiles for this display only", and try some of the others.

Comment: @benwiggy I tried. No luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please provide lots of detail. Which bit of my suggestions did you try?

Comment: Does the screen alway look blue-ish, even at startup? Profiles aren't loaded until just before you reach the desktop [not sure quite where that happens if you need to manually login] but you should be able to see the colour-shift happen as the profile is loaded normally. Also, take a photo of the screen & edit it into your question.